# C++ Bidirectional pipe - stuck trying to read from child process in a loop

Tags: c++, c++11, pipe, c++14, ipc

I am trying to make a bidirectional pipe to make a **parent** process send a message to a **child** process and wait for its answer, do something with the answer and send another message, and repeat that again and again.
The **child** process uses STDIN and STDOUT to receive and send input, and the **parent** use the messages as **c++ strings**, so they are converted before sending and after receiving, also, different messages have different (unknown)lengths.
I wrote a simple code to exemplify:

**Parent.cpp:**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

int main(){
    int parent_to_child[2];
    int child_to_parent[2];

    pipe(parent_to_child);
    pipe(child_to_parent);

    int childPID = fork();

    if(childPID == 0){
        //this is child
        close(parent_to_child[1]);//Close the writing end of the incoming pipe
        close(child_to_parent[0]);//Close the reading end of the outgoing pipe

        dup2(parent_to_child[0], STDIN_FILENO);//replace stdin with incoming pipe
        dup2(child_to_parent[1], STDOUT_FILENO);//replace stdout with outgoing pipe

        //exec child process
        char filename[] = "child.out";
        char *newargv[] = { NULL };
        char *newenviron[] = { NULL };
        execve(filename, newargv, newenviron);
    }else{
        //this is parent
        close(parent_to_child[0]);//Close the reading end of the outgoing pipe.
        close(child_to_parent[1]);//Close the writing side of the incoming pipe.

        int parent_frame = 0;
        char str_to_write[100];

        char reading_buffer;
        std::string received_str;

        do{
            //Make the frame number a cstring and append '\n'
            strcpy(str_to_write, std::to_string(parent_frame).c_str());
            strcat(str_to_write,"\n");

            write(parent_to_child[1], str_to_write, strlen(str_to_write));
            std::cout << "Parent sent: "<< str_to_write <<std::endl;


            received_str = "";
            while(read(child_to_parent[0], &reading_buffer, 1) > 0){
                received_str += reading_buffer;
            }

            std::cout << "Parent received: "<< received_str<< std::endl;
        } while (++parent_frame);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Child.cpp**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int child_frame = 0;
    char child_buffer[1024];
    do{
        std::cin >> child_buffer; //wait for father's messages
        std::cout << "CHILD received: "<< child_buffer<<" at frame "<< child_frame<<"\n"; //return message to father
    }while(++child_frame);

    return 0;
}
```

Executing Parent outputs:

```
Parent sent: 0
```

...And gets stuck

If I don't make the pipe from *child to parent* and let the parent write to STDOUT the code works as spected, as I see the responses of the child in the terminal. Thus, indicating that the child is being able to read from the parent, but for some reason, the parent can not read from child.

So my question is: why the parent can't read child output and how can this work? what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the parent's call to `read(2)` inside the innermost while-loop.

This is continually reading data until `read(2)` returns a value <= 0. But that only happens when (1) an error occurs or (2) the child closes their write end of the pipe. Thus the child sends its message, which the parent happily reads, and then just sits waiting for further data from the child. Which obviously never arrives.

The issue is your condition on the while-loop. You don't want to read until EOF or error, you want to read a full line (if you're using newlines as message delimiters). Look at `getline(3)` to make this a bit easier and avoid reading single bytes at a time, or `std::getline` if you morph the code into more of a C++ style.